# IOS voice over reads the whole table view cell content when focused

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, voiceover

I have a table view with cells that contains bunch of items similar to face book posts.
When voice over selects the contentView of the cell, it reads everything within the cell in one go. Upon swiping further, each element within the tableview cell receives focus and is read by voice over.

I am setting tableview cell's content view's accessibilityLLabel as below

```
contentView.accessibilityLabel = "Post"
```

So, as per the above code I should expect voice over to read only as "Post" when the whole content view of tableview cell is selected. However, it still reads everything within the cell in one go.

My requirement is to enable voice over selecting individual elements within the cell by swipe gesture and read them and also enable selecting the whole cell  and read as "Post" when cells contentview is selected.

Any pointers on how to avoid voice over reading the whole cell content when contentview of the cell is selected OR what is causing voice over to read everything within the cell when contentview receives focus.

Comment: Which view(s) in the view hierarchy have `isAccessibilityElement` set to true?

Comment: Only the contentview and the the elements within the tableview cell. When the contentview is selected, it reads "post" and after a brief pause says "Illustrations <followed by reading the whole content of the cell>".